# check all the checkboxes by clicking on the "ALL" checkbox using jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<body>                                           
<input type="checkbox" id="chkMain" />
<input type="checkbox" id="chkMain1" />
<input type="checkbox" id="chkMain2" />

<br>
<P><input class="child" type="checkbox" id="chk1" disabled="true" />
<input class="child" type="checkbox" id="chk" disabled="true" />
<input class="child" type="checkbox" id="chk" disabled="true" />
<input class="child" type="checkbox" id="chk" disabled="true" />
<input class="child" type="checkbox" id="chk" disabled="true" />
<input class="child" type="checkbox" id="chk" disabled="true" />
<input class="child" type="checkbox" id="chk_all" disabled="true" />ALL</p></br>


$(function(){           
    $("input[id^=chkMain]").click(function(){               
        var otherCks = $("input[id^=chkMain]").not(this);
        if( !$(this).is( ":checked" )) {                        
            $(".child").attr("disabled" , true );                                     
            otherCks.removeAttr ( "disabled" );
        }                   
        else {                        
            $(".child").removeAttr ( "disabled" );                  
            otherCks.attr("disabled" , true)
        }          
    });      
 });
```

Comment: here i want to enable all child checkboxex when clicked on "ALL" chkbox

Comment: I'm confused that your "All" checkbox is disabled. This doesn't seem to make sense.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't mentioned your issue in the question. Assuming you want to check all the checkboxes with class name child when clicking on checkbox chkMain

```
$(function(){
    $("#chk_all").click(function(){
        $("input:checkbox").attr("disabled", !(this.checked));
    });
});
```

Also you are having an invalid HTML. More than one element is having the same id.

Comment: oh,sry...assume the chkbox numbered 1 to 5 then the all chkbox is placed !!! where do i paste the above code?? after if o after else ??

Comment: its like i have 3 MAIN checkboxes !!! the above code works when chkMain1 is checked n enables the child boxes disabling the other two Main boxes(same works for other chkMain also)..the next thin i want is to chk all the child boxes when a child box chk_all is checked???

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very unclear.
There is already an answer provided to enable/disable your checkboxes. However, based upon what I could gather from your code, it seems like you are wanting to create an all check/uncheck checkbox?

If so, you could do the following as a simple check-all/uncheck-all:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input.check_all').click(function() {
        if ($(this).attr('checked'))
        {
            $('input.child, input.check_all').attr('checked', 'checked');
        }
        else
        {
            $('input.child, input.check_all').removeAttr('checked');
        }
    });
});
</script>

<input class="check_all" type="checkbox" name="foo[]" /> All<br />
<input class="child" type="checkbox" name="foo[]" /><br />
<input class="child" type="checkbox" name="foo[]" /><br />
<input class="child" type="checkbox" name="foo[]" /><br />
<input class="child" type="checkbox" name="foo[]" /><br />
<input class="child" type="checkbox" name="foo[]" /><br />
<input class="child" type="checkbox" name="foo[]" /><br />
<input class="child" type="checkbox" name="foo[]" /><br />
<input class="child" type="checkbox" name="foo[]" /><br />
<input class="child" type="checkbox" name="foo[]" /><br />
<input class="child" type="checkbox" name="foo[]" /><br />
```

Your checkboxes probably should contain a name. Also, using the same ID on multiple DOM elements is not allowed and will cause errors.